# computing $\mathrm{d}V(\zeta)$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm trying to prove that $
f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{D}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(1-z \bar{\zeta})^2} \mathrm{d} V(\zeta)
$ for $z, \zeta \in \mathbb{D}$ and I have an idea of the proof, but I am stuck in something more basic.

The reference I am looking at says for $\zeta=re^{i\theta}$, we have $\mathrm{d}V(\zeta)=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$. However, when I do the computations, this is what I get:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}V(\zeta)&= \mathrm{d}\zeta \wedge \mathrm{d}\bar{\zeta} \\
&= \mathrm{d} re^{i\theta} \wedge \mathrm{d}re^{-i\theta} \\
&= \mathrm{d} r (e^{i\theta})+(ir e^{i\theta}) \mathrm{d} \theta\wedge \mathrm{d} r (e^{-i\theta})+(-ir e^{-i\theta}) \mathrm{d} \theta \\
&= -2ir \mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}
$$
and in somehow the same way,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}V(\zeta) &= \mathrm{d}\zeta \wedge \mathrm{d}\bar{\zeta} \\
&= (\mathrm{d} x+ i\mathrm{d} y) \wedge (\mathrm{d}x -i \mathrm{d} y) \\
&= (\mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} x)-i(\mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y)+i (\mathrm{d} y \wedge \mathrm{d} x) + (\mathrm{d} y \wedge \mathrm{d}y) \\
&= -2i \mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
$$

I'd appreciate it if someone can let me know where am I wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $\textrm{d}V$ is $\textrm{d}x \wedge \textrm{d}y$ as the book says.  Writing $\textrm{d}V(\zeta)$ is just to indicate that you are integrating in the $\zeta$ plane instead of the $z$ plane.

Your mistake is thinking that $\textrm{d}V(\zeta) = \textrm{d}\zeta \wedge \textrm{d} \bar{\zeta}$.

Your  computation of $\textrm{d}\zeta \wedge \textrm{d} \bar{\zeta} = -2i \textrm{d}V(\zeta)$ is accurate.